# Exclude comments of posts in certain categories in WordPress RSS feeds

Tags: wordpress, rss, comments

So I can exclude posts in a certain category from showing in a WordPress RSS (etc) feeds, my problem is that I also need to stop comments to those posts appearing.

But going to http://www.example.com/comments/feed/ shows the comments to those posts, which should remain private.

Searched high and low, tried all sorts, so hoping some experts on here can help!

Comment: Fixed myself, used post type of the comment's parent post instead to exclude, but you could do what you want, as follows. xxx and yyy obviously dummy values!

>function custom_comment_feed_where($where) {
>global $wpdb;
>// get the post type
>$where .= " AND $wpdb->posts.post_type NOT IN (
>'xxx',
>'yyy'
>)";
>return $where;
>}
>add_filter('comment_feed_where', 'custom_comment_feed_where');`

Comment: [code]function custom_comment_feed_where($where) {
global $wpdb;
// get the post type
$where .= " AND $wpdb->posts.post_type NOT IN (
'xxx',
'yyy'
)";
return $where;
}
add_filter('comment_feed_where', 'custom_comment_feed_where');[/code]

Comment: given up trying to format the code....

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_comment_feed_where($where) {
    global $wpdb;
    // get the post type
    $where .= " AND $wpdb->posts.post_type NOT IN (
        'xxx',
        'yyy'
    )";
    return $where;
}

add_filter('comment_feed_where', 'custom_comment_feed_where');
```